# Auto focus won’t work in viewfinder on Aperture priority mode

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus, manual-mode, aperture-priority

My camera (Canon Rebel t7i) won’t auto focus in manual or aperture priority mode in viewfinder. (It works perfectly in liveview)

Maybe it’s important to say that I’ve never shot in manual mode so I wanted to learn how to shoot in Aperture Priority mode. Auto focus isn’t working in viewfinder though. I used 2 different lenses (canon 50 mm 1.8 and the kit lens) It doesn’t work on both. I tried resetting the camera. Still nothing.

It does work in auto mode in the viewfinder.

Am I doing something wrong or is something broken?

Comment: What about Tv, P mode. Does the autofocus work?

Comment: No, it doesn’t work in TV or P mode either.

Comment: Is this a new camera? There is probability you focusing subsystem do not work.

Comment: No, I’ve had it for a few years, but only now learning about other modes instead of auto mode. So I’m not sure when this issue started.

Comment: Have you tested this outdoors in bright daylight?

Comment: Not yet, I will try that tomorrow morning! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Emnsmnc The auto focus  ssue might be due to  low light.